# How to construct SQL for this scenario

Tags: sql

I have a table with 4 fields (date, AssetName, Price) and in this table I have one record per asset per business day. using this table I would like to construct a query that will give me the following

(AssetName , LastPrice, Price a month ago, Price a Year ago, Price 3 years ago) 
I would appreciate for any help

Comment: What is stopping you from writing an attempt to return the data you want?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you're interested in doing self joins back to your original table with different date criteria.

I think the following would work, but you may want to use ISNULL in the event a previous price does not exist in order to format your output accordingly.

```
SELECT A.AssetName
, A.Price as CurrentPrice
, B.Price as LastYearPrice
, C.Price as LastMonthPrice
FROM Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B -- LastYearPrice
ON A.AssetName = B.AssetName
AND A.Date = DATEADD(y, -1, B.Date)
LEFT JOIN Table C -- LastMonthPrice
ON A.AssetName = C.AssetName
AND A.Date = DATEADD(m, -1, C.Date)
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work work but it is really slow, and I have one minor problem with the query. When we  use A.Date = DATEADD(y, -1, B.Date)  as our join criteria there are some cases that there is no data for that particular date (e.g. when one month prior to today's date was a holiday or weekend) . In that case I still need to get data for a day before or after (either  one will work but if the prior day is sunday we need to go back two days to get friday's data)

Comment: Put it in the where clause instead of the join. I'll update shortly

Answer (score 0):

```
select assetname,max(lastprice) lastprice,max(price_a_month_ago) price_a_month_ago,max(price_a_year_ago) price_a_year_ago,max(price_3_years_ago) price_3_years_ago from
(
select assetname,
case when months_between(current_date,price_date) < 1 then price else null end as lastprice,
case when months_between(current_date,price_date) = 1  then price else null end as price_a_month_ago,
case when months_between(current_date,price_date) = 12  then price else null end as price_a_year_ago,
case when months_between(current_date,price_date) = 36  then price else null end as price_3_years_ago 
from ASSET_TABLE
)a group by assetname
```